# How to find the size of logical partition in a Cosmos container is reaching the 10GB limit and set alert

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I would like to to know if there is a way to find out the number of partitions in a cosmos container. Also If there is a way find the size per partition. Based on this I would like to be alerted based on a threshold that it is reaching the 10GB limit.

Comment: Have you tried this API ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db-resource-provider/collectionpartition/listusages

Answer (score 1):

You can use Azure Monitor with Log Analytics and write a query to output partition key metrics such as size. Example query below.

Doc on Azure Monitor for Cosmos DB:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/monitor-cosmos-db

Example Log Analytics query for this type of data

```
AzureDiagnostics 
| where ResourceProvider=="MICROSOFT.DOCUMENTDB" and Category=="PartitionKeyStatistics" 
| project SubscriptionId, regionName_s, databaseName_s, collectionname_s, partitionkey_s, sizeKb_s, ResourceId
```

Hope this helps.